# Is there a way to resume from where COPY TO failed?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra's COPY command (docs can be found at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html) to export a large table to CSV and have even larger was ones I need to export after this.

The command I used is:

```
COPY my_table_name TO 'my_table_name.csv'
```

After running for 12 hours (and creating a 289GB file) I got the following error:

```
Error for (3598295844520231142, 3615644561192297385): ReadFailure - Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'} (permanently given up after 349000 rows and 1 attempts)
Exported 1280 ranges out of 1281 total ranges, some records might be missing
```

I would like to know if there is a way to continue from the point of failure. I see the error shows "Exported 1280 ranges out of 1281 total ranges" is there a way to specify just the last range so I don't need to try exporting the entire table again?

The docs mention BEGINTOKEN and ENDTOKEN but I'm not clear on what those mean if they can help me.

Is there perhaps a more robust method to export a table?

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COPY` commands should be used for up to about 1 million records in a table (rule of thumb). The reason is it is pretty slow (single threaded python) and not very robust even if easy.

There are FREE tools out there to achieve the same thing. I am thinking specially of [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulk-cmd.html). To create a CSV use the `unload` command [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/unload.html)

This component provides you with many options for the export and a CHECKPOINT mechanism to restart when you stopped. The output are multiple CSV more easy to move later on.

```
dsbulk unload -url ~/data-export -k ks1 -t table1
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually, no, there isn't a way to resume a `COPY` operation.

> The docs mention BEGINTOKEN and ENDTOKEN but I'm not clear on what those mean if they can help me.

```
Error for (3598295844520231142, 3615644561192297385): ReadFailure
```

However, in your case, cqlsh did give you the token range which had the failure.  You could use the `BEGINTOKEN` and `ENDTOKEN` options to `COPY` just that token range:

```
COPY my_table_name TO 'my_table_name.csv' WITH BEGINTOKEN=3598295844520231142 AND ENDTOKEN=3615644561192297385
```

But otherwise, Cédrick is right. [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulk-cmd.html) is a much more reliable method for exporting and importing data from Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

The cqlsh `COPY` commands are intended to be used for non-production workloads, particularly if you're trying things out. It's a development tool intended for exporting/loading up to a few thousand records on small clusters.

If you think about it, the process of exporting requires a full table scan so if there are (a) lots of records, and/or (b) lots of nodes, then (c) you'll either overload your cluster or cause cqlsh to timeout.

Furthermore, the cqlsh `COPY` commands do not have the ability to retry an operation from where it last failed so it will have to start all over and re-process all the records.

The **DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)** utility was created specifically for this reason. DSBulk can export data from a Cassandra cluster to CSV or JSON format but its main feature is for bulk-loading data in CSV or JSON format.

DSBulk breaks up a table into small segments to be processed by multiple threads in parallel so it can distribute the load efficiently across nodes in the cluster.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [Introduction to DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader)
- Blog - [DSBulk Unloading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading)
- Docs - [More data export examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkUnload.html)

Note that DSBulk has a "resume" feature that allows a failed operation to be restarted from where it left off using checkpoint files. For details, see the checkpoint sections of the [DSBulk Logging options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/logging-options.html#dsbulkLoggingOptionsCheckpointEnabled).

And finally, DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!